# finding extreme points for Lagrangian with multiple inequality constraints

Tags: optimization, lagrange-multiplier, constraints

I am trying to find maximum of

\begin{equation}
f(x, y) = x^2 - xy + y - 4x
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}\label{constraints} 
\text{s.t. } 0 \leq x \leq  2 \text{ and } 0 \leq y \leq 1
\end{equation}

I got an advice to first check for the interior solution (it has none there is one saddle point at [1,-2] and afterwards check each constraint separately, but I am not sure if what I did is correct and how to proceed with finding extreme points at the boundaries

\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
0=x; 0=y \\
0=x; 1=y \\
2=x; 0=y \\
2=x; 1=y \\
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

Now we can set up 4 Lagrangians to check for each boundary:

\subsubsection*{First Lagrangian:}

\begin{equation}
\mathcal{L} = x^2 - xy + y - 4x - \lambda_1(-x) - \lambda_2 (-y) 
\end{equation}

with FOCs

\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
\frac{\partial \mathcal{L} }{\partial x} & =  2x - y -4 + \lambda_1 = 0\\
\frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{ \partial y} & =  -x + 1 + \lambda_2 = 0 \\
x&=0\\
y&=0
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

hence here $x=y=0$ and $\lambda_1 = 4$ and $\lambda_2=-1$

\subsubsection*{Second Lagrangian:}

\begin{equation}
\mathcal{L} = x^2 - xy + y - 4x - \lambda_1(-x) - \lambda_2 (-y) 
\end{equation}

with FOCs

\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
\frac{\partial \mathcal{L} }{\partial x} & =  2x - y -4 + \lambda_1 = 0\\
\frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{ \partial y} & =  -x + 1 + \lambda_2 = 0 \\
x&=0\\
y&=1
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

hence here $x=y=0$ and $\lambda_1 = 3$ and $\lambda_2=-1$

\subsubsection*{Third Lagrangian:}

\begin{equation}
\mathcal{L} = x^2 - xy + y - 4x - \lambda_1(-x) - \lambda_2 (-y) 
\end{equation}

with FOCs

\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
\frac{\partial \mathcal{L} }{\partial x} & =  2x - y -4 + \lambda_1 = 0\\
\frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{ \partial y} & =  -x + 1 + \lambda_2 = 0 \\
x&=0\\
y&=1
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

hence here $x=y=0$ and $\lambda_1 = 3$ and $\lambda_2=-1$

\subsubsection{Fourth Lagrangian}

\begin{equation}
\mathcal{L} = x^2 - xy + y - 4x - \lambda_1(-x) - \lambda_2 (-y) 
\end{equation}

with FOCs

\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
\frac{\partial \mathcal{L} }{\partial x} & =  2x - y -4 + \lambda_1 = 0\\
\frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{ \partial y} & =  -x + 1 + \lambda_2 = 0 \\
x&=2\\
y&=1
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

Comment: You seem to check the corner points, not the boundaries; why are all your Lagrangians the same? Why not write one Lagrangian with all four constraints?

Comment: Given the optimal value of $y$, the function is convex in $x$ and its maximum over $x \in [0,2]$ must lie on the boundary, i.e., either $x=0$ or $x=2$. So the global max $(x^*,y^*)$ is quite easy to find without Lagrange multipliers, as we know it suffices to assume $x^*\in \{0,2\}$.

Comment: @LinAlg well I just was told this would be simpler but I am not opposed to it I am just not sure how to solve it with so many unknowns

Comment: @Michael by the way how would I prove that function is convex in this case? I know without lagrangian I would look at the eigenvalues of hessian but I am not sure how the matrix should look with inequality constraints

Comment: This is convex in $x$ for any given $y$, which can easily be proven by taking two derivatives with respect to $x$.

Comment: Since the feasible set is compact, and the cost convex, the $\max$ must occur at an extreme point of the feasible set. Hence there are only 4 points to check. Forget the Lagrangian.

Comment: @copper.hat so I just need to substitute points (0,0), (0,1),(2,0),(2,1) into the objective function and see which gives highest result?

Comment: @1muflon1: That is correct. Note that, in general, if $f$ is convex, then $\max_{x \in [a,b]} f(x) = \max(f(a),f(b))$. In finite dimensions, a compact set is the convex hull of its extreme points (see Rockafellar, Convex Analysis, Theorem 18.5).

Comment: @1muflon1: Actually, an equivalent, but nicer statement is that $\max_{x \in \operatorname{co} \{ p_1,...,p_m\}} f(x) = \max_k f(p_k)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $f$ is a quadratic function having a saddle point it is **not** convex.

In order to find the maximum of $f$ on the boundary $\partial R$ of the given rectangular domain $R$ just pull back $f$ to the four edges of $R$, i.e., consider the four auxiliary functions
$$\eqalign{&\phi_0(y):=f(0,y)=y,\quad\phi_2(y)=f(2,y)=-y-4\qquad\qquad(0\leq y\leq 1),\cr &\psi_0(x):=f(x,0)=(x-2)^2-4,\quad \psi_1(x):=f(x,1)=(x-2.5)^2-5.25\qquad(0\leq x\leq2)\ .\cr}$$
Since all four of these functions are monotone on the relevant intervals we can conclude that
$$\max_{(x,y)\in R}f(x,y)=\max\bigl\{f(0,0),f(2,0),f(0,1),f(2,1)\bigr\}=1\ .$$